# Magento 2 Functional Testing using Phantom JS (or other headless)

Tags: magento2, testing, unit-tests

Curious as to if there is a way to configure the functional testing xml, in order to allow for other web-drivers such as Phatomjs? I already know of the way to change them to Chome and Firefox, but looking for a headless solution if at all possible in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted this for a few hours, with limited success. I did successfully run the tests, though the first handful failed, so I just terminated the test. I followed this guide: [Dev Docs - Introduction to the Functional Testing Framework](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/mtf/mtf_introduction.html).

You will notice that the functional tests use a combination of Selenium and PHPUnit. So, I found that the wealth of advice pertaining to Selenium also applied to the M2 functional tests. For instance, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568899/does-selenium-support-headless-browser-testing) seems relevant. Selenium also offers [a guide on their site](http://www.seleniumframework.com/cucumber-jvm-3/headless-testing/).

I would recommend trying to configure the tests for "normal" execution first - that is, not headless, just in your desktop environment. Once that is working, then I would set my sights on the headless execution. Yeah, phantom.js could potentially apply. The method I found was using Xvcb (X virtual frame buffer). You can initialize this from the command line, but my understanding is you are creating a separate X display, so it's as if Firefox actually is running with a GUI. However, you can't see it, though theoretically I suppose you could "connect" to that X display.

Good luck. I found the documentation pretty thorough, even though I couldn't ultimately get the tests to pass.

Comment: Thank you for you feed back. Although that is a healthy alternative I still would prefer either find a proper implementation into Magento's code base (following standards, no hacks). I can, obviously, run ghost or phantomjs manually, meaning independent of Magento. With that being said, thank you again for your post. I'm hoping to find a resolution in time--unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "hacks." This is how the community runs Selenium in a headless configuration. https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium+headless

Comment: My definition of hack in this scenario is as followed.

Hack: A workarounds by means not deemed standard to the community of a  given platform.